# How to map data from csv to a nested avro schema

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Hypothetically if I have a schema like below

```
    {
    "name": "phoneNumber",
    "type": {
      "type": "record",
      "name": "internalNumber",
      "namespace": "com.wiki",
      "fields": [{
        "name": "areacode",
        "type": "string",
      }, {
        "name": "phone",
        "type": ["null", "string"],
        "doc": "Acutal full number",
        "default": null
      }]
    }
  }
```

and I have a csv that has this data scattered into multiple columns like :

```
areaCode  phoneNumber
+1        1234512345
```

How can I from a pig script get an avro file like :

```
"phoneNumber" : {
 "areacode" : "+1",
  "phone" : "1234512345"
}
```

Since its nested.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = LOAD 'path' USING CSVLoader as (areaCode: chararray, phoneNumber: chararray);
B = foreach A generate (areaCode, phoneNumber as phone) as phoneNumber;
STORE B INTO 'path' using AvroStorage;
```

You'll need csvloader  and avrostorage from piggybank